# Dynamic field name in queryset annotation

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I need to rename output field name with incoming variable value. There is a function:

```
def metric_data(request, test_id, metric):
    metric_name = metric
    data = ServerMonitoringData.objects. \
        filter(test_id=test_id). \
        annotate(timestamp=RawSQL("((data->>%s)::timestamp)", ('timestamp',))).\
        annotate(metric=RawSQL("((data->>%s)::numeric)", (metric,))). \
        values('timestamp', "metric")
```

So in this case no matter what value comes with the variable **metric** the output is looking like:

```
 {"timestamp": "0:31:02", "metric": "8.82414500398"}
```

I need to have an output with a key names equals to metric variable (if metric == 'CPU_iowait'):

```
{"timestamp": "0:31:02", "CPU_iowait": "8.82414500398"}
```

Tryed to use something like this:

```
    metric_name = metric
...
    annotate(metric_name=F('metric')).\
    values('timestamp', metric_name)
```

But it is trying to find 'CPU_iowait' column when exists 'metric_name'. 
So is there any way to pass field name as a variable ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# use dict to map the metric's name to a RawSQL query 
# and pass it as keyword argument to `.annotate`.
metric_mapping = {
    metric: RawSQL("((data->>%s)::numeric)", (metric,))
}
queryset.annotate(**metric_mapping)
```

Comment: There's a typo in your `annotate` call.